# Spark RDD: Sum one column without creating SQL DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there an efficient way to sum up the values in a column in spark RDD directly? I do not want to create a SQL DataFrame just for this.

I have an RDD of LabeledPoint in which each LabeledPoint uses a sparse vector representation. Suppose I am interested in sum of the values of first feature.
The following code does not work for me:

```
//lp_RDD is RDD[LabeledPoint]
var total = 0.0
for(x <- lp_RDD){
    total += x.features(0)
}
```

The value of totalAmt after this loop is still 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to extract the first element from the `feature` vector using `RDD.map` and then sum them all up using `DoubleRDDFunctions.sum`:

```
val sum: Double = rdd.map(_.features(0)).sum()
```